# Enzyme kinetics: recommended literature to grasp the concepts better

Tags: biochemistry, biophysics, book-recommendation, enzyme-kinetics

I have had a few biochemistry courses, but I still feel confused and a bit scared each time they try to explain and apply enzyme kinetics or even chemometrics in different situation during class. On our last lecture we had kinetics regarding:

- Pingpong reactions (with two substrates A, B):

  $V_0 = \dfrac{K_{cat}[E]* [A][B]}{K_m^B [A] * [B] * [A][B]} $
- General reactions (with two substrates A, B):

  $V_0 = \dfrac{K_{cat}[E]* [A][B]}{K_m^B [A] * K_s^A * [B] * [A][B]} $

And we also had something about analyzing the "principle component" in multivariate data, from enzyme kinetic measurements (as effect of e.g. pH of temperature).

I really don't understand this, or how I would apply this - or analyze my data if I have two substrates.

**Question**: In general, is there a good web site which goes beyond the normal Michaelis menten analysis, or a very good book which explains both the basic and more complex scenarios regarding analysis/application of enzyme kinetics for biochemists?

Comment: Is there a textbook for your course? If so, which one? At the undergraduate level, Voet & Voet is the most comprehensive for my money (and that is a lot of money).  However, for detailed discussion of kinetic mechanisms, like Dan Koshland's ping-pong model, you probably need a book focusing exclusively on enzyme kinetics (not a general textbook)

Comment: there is no textbook, just the teacher drawing on the board. Its okay to memorize exactly what they say, and then just paste it in on an exam.. but i would really like to understand this. Thank you for your suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always used the book ["Enzyme Structure and Mechanism"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716716143) by Alan Fersht. ([Structure and Mechanism in Protein Science: A Guide to Enzyme Catalysis and Protein Folding](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716732688) is the latest version, published in 1998.) Both in some courses I did and when working on (complex) enzymatic mechanisms. It's a classic (so a bit old maybe), but it covers all the basics and includes most of the common complex mechanisms like ping-pong. I don't know if it will teach you how to analyze multivariate data, so maybe you need something else for that.

Comment: Yes, thank you for mentioning this one. It is excellent, and it is a classic. I have an older version somewhere but I could not remember the name.